# Adding an Interior door on bottom of stairs

Tags: doors, stairs

I need to place a door at the bottom of these stairs. I will be having a baby in a few months and need the separation/noise reduction from the downstairs. There is no option for a door at the top.  I was thinking an accordion or bifold door but not sure how to go about it. Any ideas? I am willing to try anything.

[image: bottom of the stairs]

[image: side of bottom of stairs]

[image: top of stairs]

[image: side of top of stairs]

[image: looking down at stairs]

[image: another looking down]

could we put a door in this place?
looking from bottom of stairs on the left hand side before going up main stairs?

Comment: Parenting protip: Shielding an infant from noise is a sure way to generate a fussy sleeper. I'd wait until you know this is a real need.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and see the [help]. Your question is rather broad. Also, I'm not clear on where the noise would come from. Can't that room have a door?

Comment: Will a door at the left of the stairs (looking up from the bottom) work for your sound separation?

Comment: yes it could work on the left, but how would we go about that?

Answer (score 4):

You have no room or options to have it at the bottom of the stairs.   There must be a landing area before a door - that is code.    You can have a door at the top of the stairs but obviously that requires the staircase rail to be walled in.

You can obviously do whatever you want outside of code.   But you will be tearing up your house and will have to remove the door before selling and it will be somewhat dangerous no matter what you go with.

Comment: Would something like a curtain come under door in the code?  I am thinking yes, but the area at the bottom does not placing a door easy, even without the need for a landing.

Comment: A heavy curtain upstairs, running along the balustrade would have adequate landings on either side of the opening, and it would be easily reversible.

Comment: You could add a heavy curtain at the bottom.    Especially if you can have them work like drapes and walk in between.   That would just be a couple of holes on the ceiling which is much easier to deal with.